# Use of the integrals in the graph theory

Tags: functional-analysis, graph-theory, manifolds, triangulation

I hope to know some good references about the use of integrals to study the graph theory:

1. For example, it seems that
   $$
   \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dx \exp(-x^2/2+\lambda x^3/3!)
   $$
   whose coefficients in the $V$ powers of $\lambda$, the coefficient of $\lambda^V$ counts the possible trivalent graphs of $V$ vertices.
2. For example, it seems that
   $$
   \int dM \exp(\text{Tr}(-M^2/2+\lambda M^3/3!))
   $$
   where $M$ is a rank-$N$ Hermitian matrix.
   The coefficient of $N^{2-2g}\lambda^V$ counts the possible trivalent graphs of $V$ vertices on a genus-$g$ Riemann surfaces.

> - Are there some similar or more general statements of such integrals in the graph theory? Any References are welcome.
> - Some intuitive way to obtain the above formulas?

Comment: The first integral does not integrate at $+\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, if you know about that, you may write the answer - I saw this integral from a seminar talk.

Comment: I double checked, and it was how the speaker wrote down the expression  - I wrote it the same way as he did.

Comment: https://www.wellesley.edu/sites/default/files/assets/kayll-colloq.pdf

Comment: Can you explain how the first integral implies that there is one trivalent graph on four vertices?

Comment: you can for example learn the 1st integral at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hHKYwz01bA

Comment: Where in the hour-long lecture can one see the first integral?

Comment: 8 min 05 sec in the lecture above

Comment: @ncmathsadist Witten says that if $\lambda$ is imaginary it converges, but the point is to make an asymptotic expansion with respect to generic $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

In paper I was reading recently, the author said "it is well known that many enumerative problems in graph theory can be solved using Gaussian integrals," and cited the following book:

Sergei K. Lando and Alexander K. Zvonkin, *Graphs on surfaces and their applications*, Encyclopaedia of Mathematical Sciences, vol. 141, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2004, With an appendix by Don B. Zagier, Low-Dimensional
Topology, II. [MR 2036721](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2036721). ([Springer](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540002031), or [Springer Link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-540-38361-1)).

Chapter 3 discusses matrix integral methods.  It gives some examples, for instance a matrix integral for enumerating $1$-vertex graphs that fill a surface of genus $g$, or enumerating planar $4$-regular graphs that are the generic image of a circle.  Perhaps the book describes the techniques well enough that you can figure out the construction of your given integrals.

A note to Proposition 3.2.10 mentions how you can disregard genus information by setting the matrix size to $1\times 1$.  This appears to be the transformation from your second integral to your first.  Given what I've picked up so far, perhaps it ought to be "where $M$ is an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix" rather than "where $M$ is a rank-$n$ Hermitian matrix."

---

After looking at a paper by one of the book's authors,

A. Zvonkin, *Matrix integrals and map enumeration: an accessible introduction*, Mathematical and Computer
Modelling **26** (1997), no. 8-10, 281–304, Combinatorics and physics (Marseilles, 1995). [MR 1492512](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1492512)

I think I can tell you what the terms of the integral represent.  The first part is that a Gaussian measure on the space of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices is given by $d\mu(M)=\exp(\operatorname{tr}(-M^2/2))dM$, though in the paper equation (6) has some more normalization terms.  The second part is $$\exp(\operatorname{tr}(\lambda M^3/3!))=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\operatorname{tr}(\lambda M^3/3!)^k/k!=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\lambda/3!)^{nk}\operatorname{tr}(M^3)^k/k!.$$
I do not understand what the $3!$ is doing in there, except perhaps to remove the dihedral symmetry of a $3$-valent vertex.  The $k!$ is likely to remove the vertex-renaming symmetry.  The paper says that $\int \operatorname{tr}(M^3)^k\,d\mu$ expanded in terms of $N$ has coefficients giving the number of $3$-valent graphs with $k$ vertices in a particular genus.  Integrating the infinite sum makes it so the coefficients of $N$ are power series in $\lambda$, the coefficients of which give the number of graphs of a particular number of vertices.

Comment: thanks +1, for the answer

Comment: @wonderich I was puzzled what the $M^2$ was doing in Witten's version of the integral, and it appears to be from the Gaussian measure on the space of Hermitian matrices.  I added what I understand of this to the answer.

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between an × Hermitian matrix vs a rank- Hermitian matrix?

Comment: A Hermitian matrix is one whose conjugate transpose is itself (so the zero matrix is Hermitian).  A rank-$n$ Hermitian matrix that's $n \times n$ would be an invertible Hermitian matrix.  I think the non-invertible Hermitian matrices are a measure-0 set, so as far as the integrals go the distinction might not matter.

Comment: Sorry, I thought a rank- matrix is a × matrix, please correct me what I was wrong?

Comment: @wonderich The [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)) is the dimension of the image of the matrix.  An $n\times n$ matrix has a rank anywhere from $0$ to $n$.